# How to know whether a particular video file (.mp4) is busy or not?

Tags: file, video, video-streaming, wowza

I have a media server application implemented with the help of Wowza (on Linux, Centos). There are some mp4 files stored in my local directory. I am streaming these files whenever any client requests them. At some point in time, all these files need to be deleted from the local directory, through bash/python script. Before deleting, I need to make sure that no client is accessing the video files. How can I know whether a particular video file is getting streamed or not at the present time?

I have tried the following commands, but no luck.

> 1) fuser xyz.mp4
>
> 2) lsof | grep xyz.mp4

Plz, suggest if you know any other alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an OS-platform solution, but rather implements the built-in HTTPProviders in your Wowza software. If you query the following URL:
http://localhost:8086/connectioncounts?flat
It should return an XML output that lists the stream names currently being played. For example:

```html
<WowzaStreamingEngine>
<Stream vhostName="_defaultVHost_" applicationName="vod" appInstanceName="_definst_" streamName="sample.mp4" sessionsFlash="0" sessionsCupertino="3" sessionsSanJose="0" sessionsSmooth="0" sessionsRTSP="0" sessionsMPEGDash="0" sessionsTotal="3"/>
</WowzaStreamingEngine>
```

The above output shows that sample.mp4 is currently being played. The ?flat option simplifies the output. You would then only need to parse the streamnames.